# File naming convention in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

While at WWDC I noticed a file naming convention in. One of the demos that I had not seen before.  The example had :

```
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.m
AppDelegate_animation.m
```

The _animation file semed to have all animation related code.

Is this naming convention documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any Docs on the underscore, but here's a good start:
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think apple has much in terms of documenting something as arbitrary as naming your object code files ..

Its an interesting idea, not even using a category, simply splitting the object code out and have the same header file be in charge of them both. (I personally prefer categories, seems like a more formal interface)

ie:

```
AppDelegate+Animations.h
AppDelegate+Animations.m
```